# Why can't I assign for loop to a variable?

Tags: javascript

So I am just wondering why the following code dosen't work. I am looking for a similar strategy to put the for loop in a variable.

```
var whatever = for (i=1;i<6;i++) {
console.log(i)
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect `whatever` to contain when the for loop completes?

Comment: How do you expect this to work? What would you want to do with your for-in-a-variable after that?

Comment: You can asign a function to a variable. So include the loop in a function: var test = function(){ for(var i = 1; i < 6; i++){console.log(i);}}; test();

Comment: It sounds like what you might be interested in is something like First-class functions. I'd suggest taking a look at the Wikipedia article and getting a better grasp of what it is you're actually asking for.

Comment: @lanzz in languages that provide this sort of behavior, the value might be something like the value of the last statement executed in the last iteration. That way, you'd write a "reduce" loop as a `for`` loop that initializes an object, then computes a value on each iteration, ending the iteration with an updating assignment to the "collector" variable. That way the assignment expression value would end up as the value of the loop. (It doesn't actually work that way of course :-)

Comment: @Pointy: This seems like quite a contrived language feature. I'm curious now, any actual examples of such languages?

Comment: @lanzz well Erlang is the only one I'm familiar with, though it doesn't have `for` loops (or any loops for that matter; you do everything with recursive function calls). But the Erlang `case` statement is part of the expression syntax, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because a `for` loop is a **statement** and in JavaScript statements don't have values.  It's simply not something provided for in the syntax and semantics of the language.

In some languages, every statement is treated as an expression (Erlang for example). In others, that's not the case. JavaScript is in the latter category.

It's kind-of like asking why horses have long stringy tails and no wings.

*edit* — look into things like the Underscore library or the "modern" add-ons to the Array prototype for "map" and "reduce" and "forEach" functionality. Those allow iterative operations in an expression evaluation context (at a cost, of course).

Comment: you could  put your loop into a function, though, which is probably what you want.

Comment: @Pointy, no wings? I don't know what kind of horses you've been looking at. :)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose what you look for is **function**:

```
var whatever = function(min, max) {
  for (var i = min; i < max;  ++i) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

... and later ...

```
whatever(1, 6);
```

This approach allows you to *encapsulate* the loop (or any other code, even declaring another functions) within a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that for loops do not return values.  You could construct an array with enough elements to hold all the iterations of your loop, then assign to it within the loop:

```
arry[j++] = i;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but it seems that you might want to check out anonymous functions. With an anonymous function you could do this:

```
var whatever = function(){
 for (var i=1;i<6;i++) {
  console.log(i);
 }
};
```

and then

```
whatever(); //runs console.log(i) i times.
```